# Print an array from user input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create an array from user input in JavaScript and display the latest array as the numbers are appended to the array. The numbers are not getting printed.
Kindly help.

HTML part :

```
<textarea form = "arrays" cols = 10 rows = 2 id = "num">
    </textarea><br />

<form id = "arrays" method = "" onsubmit="arrAppend(document.getElementById('num').value);">
<input type ="submit" value="Append" />
</form>
```

JavaScript part :

```
<script>

    var myarr = [];
    function arrAppend(num) {
        myarr.push(+num);
        text = "";
        for (var x = 0; x< myarr.length; x++) {
            text += myarr[x];
        }
        console.log(text);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: you need to understand what a `submit` does ... fully

Comment: @JaromandaX : In the text area, user will enter a number and click append. On click, the number should be added to the array(push) and also displayed on screen. As the numbers are added, the text displayed to the user should also reflect the elements added.

Comment: I think there is an unintended extra plus sign in there. It should be  `myarr.push(num);` instead of `myarr.push(+num);`

Comment: @Titus I believe that is intended to coerce the string value into an integer

Comment: use [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: @AnuvratTiku - I realised what you were trying to do, and changed my comment - you need to understand the full effects of `submit`

Comment: @JaromandaX : I think i partly understand what you mean.. What if I use a button and associate the onclick with the javascript fucntion ?? would that work

Comment: or ... why use a form at all if you aren't submitting anything to a server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working :

HTML :

```
<input type = "text"
   id = "addNumber" />

<input type = "button"
   id = "addToArray"
   value = "Append"
   onclick = "arrAppend();" />
```

JavaScript :

```
function arrAppend() {
        myarr[x] = document.getElementById('addNumber').value;
        alert("Element : "+myarr[x]+" is added at index "+x);
        x++;

        document.getElementById('addNumber').value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea form = "arrays" cols = 10 rows = 2 id = "num">
</textarea><br />
<input type ="submit" value="Append" onclick="arrAppend(document.getElementById('num').value);"/>
```

why do you need a form? are you submitting something to the server? when you submit a form it will clear the global array as well.